# Append URL parameter to server.xml datasource

Tags: java, mysql, kotlin, jndi, tomcat8

Ive been provided a mysql datasource to work with defined in my tomcat server.xml file, and I do not have the power to edit the datasource directly. However, I've run into an exception on zeroed timestamp conversion - which would typically require me to edit the URL on the datasource to include a suffix like `?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`. I'm accessing the datasource via JndiDatasourceLookup - is there a way for me to programmatically add that suffix onto the connection?

Comment: I guess that if that was possible it could be a security vulnerability.

Comment: After further consideration I suppose you're entirely correct. I hadnt thought of it that way